# Flexbox overflow scrollbar displaying on body instead of inner elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

**The Problem:**

In a full-size app layout (100% width, 100% height) using flexbox with overflow, the scrollbars do not display for overflow-y in Firefox, IE, or Edge. They do display properly in Chrome. Rather than having a vertical scrollbar in FF/IE/Edge on the element, the scrollbar is applied to the entire page.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried adding, as mentioned in several other SO answers, to add `min-height: 0;` to the flex elements / parents. I haven't been able to get this solution to work, but perhaps I am doing something wrong.

**Screenshots:**

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

**Example:**

https://codepen.io/gunn4r/pen/WEoPjN

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.canvas {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="h-100">
  <div class="h-100 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-4">Top Bar</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row no-gutter flex-grow">

      <div class="col-9 px-0 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
          <div class="canvas bg-success">
            Canvas
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-danger py-3">
          Canvas Footer
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
        <div class="sidebar-item">Sidebar</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-2">Overall Footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the problem stems from this section of your code:

```css
.canvas-wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

You want this element to have scrollbars. However, the element has no defined height.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):*

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container
>   must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or
>   `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

Chrome doesn't seem to care about the height requirement. The other browsers do.

This should be enough to make it work across browsers:

```css
.canvas-wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1 0 1px;
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1 0 1px; /* NEW */
}

.canvas {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="h-100">
  <div class="h-100 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-4">Top Bar</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row no-gutter flex-grow">
      
      <div class="col-9 px-0 d-flex flex-column">
         <div class="canvas-wrapper">
             <div class="canvas bg-success">
               Canvas
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-danger py-3">
          Canvas Footer
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
        <div class="sidebar-item">Sidebar</div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-2">Overall Footer</div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Of course...+1...I tried with `flex-grow: 1`, which didn't work so went for the _absolute position variant_

Comment: Even better! I appreciate the MDN reference, I missed that part!

Answer (score 3):

When using percent for height on element, all its ascendants also need a height set, and if all will have percent, one need to set it all the way up to the html/body.

When combined with Flexbox this can get really tricky to solve, as when one need to set `height: 100%` on all ascendants, other unwanted render issues can cause the layout to break.

Here is one solution, which work perfect cross browser, where an extra wrapper, `canvas-fix`, for the `canvas` is added, and then with `position: absolute` we can make this work.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/41tdfu3L/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}
.canvas-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;                     /*  take all remaining space  */
  width: 100%;                      /*  full width  */
  position: relative;               /*  for the absolute positioned fix  */
}
.canvas-fix {                       /*  added rule  */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.canvas {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="h-100">
  <div class="h-100 container-fluid d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-4">Top Bar</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row no-gutter flex-grow">

      <div class="col-9 px-0 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
          <div class="canvas-fix">
            <div class="canvas bg-success">
               Canvas
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-danger py-3">
          Canvas Footer
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
        <div class="sidebar-item">Sidebar</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12 py-2">Overall Footer</div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great answer! I was worried about when increasing height on things like footer dynamically that it would cause issues, but since the absolutely positioned element is nested under the relative element, everything works perfect. You're the man!